# How to predict the output of a solar panel depending upon weather conditions for real time hardware simulation?

Tags: microcontroller, solar-cell, power-engineering, optimization, solar-energy

I want to build a system for smart grid which can optimize the grid power, load and battery charging to reduce my costs for grid power. For the optimization problem, I must know the current date to optimize the overall system, so the problem for me is how can I predict the solar power to optimize the system for the next hour. I want to know if there is a controller algorithm that will predict the power from a solar panel and then decide the power to system for optimization.

In my matlab simulation, I implemented a clear-sky model that estimates the solar insolation according to the altitude angle (Chapter 7 of Gilbert Masters' book *Renewable and Efficient Electric Power Systems* ) . By using this insolation data, I want to predict the power in real hardware and then allow the controller to decide how to operate for the next hour, depending upon the previous hour's values. 
This insolation data that I have calculated is not predicted (it is estimated); we don't know the weather condition for the next day, or even the next hour.

What algorithm or controller must I have to  use to predict the solar insolation for use in a real-time hardware simulation depending upon the weather conditions?

Comment: So there is no secondary source of power? Just the panel itself? In my area it can go from solid overcast to clear skies in less than an hour. (We have a giant wind tunnel called the Columbia Gorge nearby.) You'd need a lot of information to make predictions here.

Comment: i have grid another source of electricty that i mentioned above.

Comment: I was reading your desire to predict and focused on that. But yes, I see the answer to my first question there. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @jonk ,Actually i want your decision . if you know please help me

Comment: Actually, I think your question is interesting, though I don't feel I understand why and what your goals actually are yet. And given my lack of knowledge about your goals and instead projecting my own thoughts onto that ignorance, perhaps actually a little difficult to achieve. But you might write more about why you need this. That might help me (or, perhaps more importantly, others here.)

Comment: "controller must decied how to operate in next hour depending upon the previous hour value" - why?

Comment: You want an estimator for expected solar power, is that correct? While solar elevation can be calculated, weather can only be predicted. What data do you have available for the prediction? Only past power readings?

Comment: Dear @jonk , sorry if it is not understanding for you. but you can help me that you unerstand about this question.

Comment: Dear @Andreas I have estimted solar insolation data from the Clear Sky model. i want ot know just is there a technique that i can predict solar outptu power for next hour on the base of previous hour.

Comment: @Fame313 I don't understand the question, though. I can only project by biases onto it. I do understand that if you ignore weather entirely and assume a clear sky model, that you can make predictions. But **you** are the one that brought up the subject of weather. Not me. So you immediately complicated the question by that fact. And left me with only projecting my ideas onto you, to work from. That's not a good thing. You need to carefully define **why** you brought up weather.

Comment: Let's see if I got this right. You want to forecast the weather in the next hour based on the last and using the cloud coverage results to estimate the capacity of the solar panels. This is easy to do in the US as NOAA has web services that gives the percent cloud coverage forecast for the next hour. You need to measure the panels output hourly and then compared it with the cloud coverage from the actual historical data.  Or measure the output, look at the sky and estimate the cloud coverage.

Comment: yes Dear @Misunderstood , you are right , that is the idear i want to do in actual hardware. can you please help me regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short term prediction of solar irradiation can be tricky, especially in cloudy days.

For daily average based on a year there are software like PVSyst which is probably the most advanced solar plant forecasting software out there, used by major banks for plant forecast.

Running a simulation with this software will give you a very good starting point but won't account for daily climate, which I guess you could use weather forecast and refine the daily power simulation given by the software, with empiric method or why not some machine learning.

Comment: Dear @Damien ,, Thanks for answering to my question . this is good software . i try to use it . can you tell me that will it not give me online predictio of solar power. i mean i have to optimize the power for next hour depending upon the decision of privious hours.

Comment: Dear @Fame313, As said before short term prediction can be tricky, if the day is plain sunny then it's relatively easy as you can pretty much know how much irradiation you should receive for any given position, if it gets cloudy, rainy, or any type of overcast then you will need to work with local sensor. This is a big question recently raised for Smart Grid and gird balancing and has no simple answer, weather forecast, satellite imagery and irradiation sensor around the plant with good software is probably the closest it can get in our days

Comment: You can get real time temperature (maybe pressure humidity) data from other smartphone users in your region. This can be used to predict data. Some apps and startups are already trying to do this. But this may not be accurate enough to predict small deviations.